# How to stop WebPack dev server from trying to handle Worker Blob URL's

Tags: web-worker, webpack-5

I'm trying to rejigger my usage of web worker pooling to eliminate redundant server requests. In my existing solution, I'm loading workers pretty straightforwardly like this:

```js
const worker = new Worker(`${src}?v=${version}`);
```

This happens `N` times for each worker pool. WebPack has no problem with this. But, in production, the `N` requests are superfluous, wasteful, and seem to introduce a little unnecessary latency. So, I'd like to get rid of them. To that end, I'm trying to load my worker code with a cached/debounced `fetch()` and feed the contents into the worker with a blob URL.

```js
const worker = getBundleBlobURI(src).then(uri => {
    return new Worker(uri);
});
```

Functionally, the worker is loading and operational. But locally, WebPack is now trying and failing to reconnect to `ws://0.0.0.0:9999/ws` on repeat, *flooding* the console with errors in the process.

How do make it stop?

---

My current workaround is *essentially* to use blobs only in staging + prod:

```js
const isLocal = checkIfHostnameIsLocalhost(); // more or less

if (isLocal) {
  const worker = new Worker(src);
} else {
  const worker = getBundleBlobURI(src).then(uri => {
    return new Worker(uri);
  });
}
```

But, because I'm running slightly different code in dev environments, this comes with the risk of caching catastrophic regressions *late* (possibly even in production).

Comment: How come the cached version isn't used already?

Comment: I've edited to clarify that it's a *blob* URL, not a Data URI as the function name probably suggested. Are you suggesting I'm missing cache control headers? Or, asking why the Blobbed URL version isn't using the cache? (If the latter, of course it *is*; but it still results in a local/special HTTP request to the cache.)

Comment: Speaking of those cache control headers, it looks like I have some more exploration to do there. In some cases the requests *are* using the cached version. But, it looks like any time the cache is expired, the browser is making `N` duplicate requests *simultaneously*. It felt like I could get better control over this with a blog URL, But, perhaps a good-enough mechanism would be to just pre-load the URL's.

Comment: So `src` in the first  `new Worker(`${src}?v=${version}`);` is already a `blob:` URI? I was assuming it was pointing to a .js file on your server, and was wondering why that .js isn't cached. As for caching blob: URIs, browser won't cache it, e.g if the blob URI is revoked, they won't be able to fetch it anymore.

Comment: Maybe the question is unclear. The first snippet shows the existing code. The 2nd snippet is what I'm trying to move to, which is what causes WebPack HMR to go nuts.